# CakePHP: how to fetch data from the database based on created time

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I am making a facebook like website. For that I want to implement "long polling" to dynamically update users wall with new posts.

Here is a pseudo code for what I have planned

```
//when user first open my website
loadPostsNormally();
var lastTime = current_time;
function update(){
$.getJSON('/some_other_page_which_will_fetch_the_contents_created_after_lastTime_and_encode_it_to_json/'+lastTime,function(){
lastTime = current_time;
showNewPostsOnWall();
}

setInterval(update,2000);
```

Now the problem is with my page `some_other_page_which_will_fetch_the_contents_created_after_lastTime_and_encode_it_to_json`

```
public function some_other_page_which_will_fetch_the_contents_created_after_lastTime_and_encode_it_to_json($timestamp){
    //fetch_all_data_created_after_this_timestamp_but_how ??
}
```

I want to fetch from my Post model and the time in my 'created' field of posts table is like `2014-11-19 22:34:09`

Sorry for using a very layman language to describe the problem. I used that because I have not yet started it and I'm only making a plan to approach that problem in my head.

Comment: I don't see a question in your post...

Comment: I want to know how to fetch all data created after a given time in CakePHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o just fetch data , it's simple just use conditions :

```
$results = $this->Model->find('all',array(
                            'conditions'=>array('Model.date_creation >'=>  '2014-11-20'),
                            'recursive'=>1)
                    );
```

Comment: This will fetch data created at `2014-11-20` or all data created after `2014-11-20` ?

Comment: all data after  i've use ">" , for the data created at 2014-11-20 don't use any symbol , for different from that date use "<>" .

Comment: recursive 2 is a bad idea.  look into containable instead.

Comment: @Dave , you're right i forget to remove it . thanks for the remark.

Comment: recursive 1 is still a bad idea.  look into containable instead.

Answer (score 0):

How to fetch data based on a time interval?

So you have the $start and the $end.

```
$start = '1800-01-01 00:00:00' //Januuary 1, 1800 or whatever you choose
$end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Now

SELECT *
FROM `Posts` p
WHERE (
p.data_created
BETWEEN $start
AND $end
)
```

Sweet! Now you can fetch all day long.